# Prefixed columns are not allowed in the column list of a PIVOT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have this query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT DIAL) as CALL_SUMMARY,APP,DEST_URI
FROM
test.dbs
PIVOT (COUNT(DIAL) FOR APP IN(phone, mobile)) as log_status_new
WHERE
ID_DATE >= '2019-07-08 16:41:42'
AND  ID_DATE < '2020-07-08 16:41:42'
GROUP BY APP,DEST_URI ;
```

But it returns this error:

> SQL Error [254] [S0001]: Prefixed columns are not allowed in the column list of a PIVOT operator

Sample Data:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|   DIAL   |   APP    | DEST_URI |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 5656     | phone    |        1 |
| 5657     | phone    |        2 |
| 5456     | mobile   |        6 |
| 5898     | mobile   |        9 |
| 5656     | phone    |        4 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

To:

```
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| DIAL     | PHONE  | MOBILE |  DEST_URI  |
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
| 5656     | 1      |        |   1        |
| 5657     | 1      |        |   2        |
| 5456     |        |  1     |   6        |
| 5898     |        |  1     |   9        |
| 5656     | 1      |        |   4        |
+----------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: `PIVOT` goes *after* your `WHERE`, not before it. Have a look at the examples in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#basic-pivot-example) on how to write a `PIVOT`, as there are other areas your query is deformed as well; though I personally suggest using conditional aggregation over the more restrictive `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: This code really doesn't make sense.  Can you provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Gordon is right though, it looks like you want to count the rows where the value of `APP` is either `'phone'` or '`mobile'`, and the get a `DISTINCT` `COUNT` of that `COUNT`? That's going to always be `1`. But you're then returning `APP` in the `SELECT`, when you've already aggregated it in the `PIVOT`. It's all over the place.

Comment: Hope I helped you with my edit. Sorry for the misunderstood but I am totally new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have isn't a `PIVOT`. YOu just need a couple of `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT DIAL,
       CASE APP WHEN 'phone' THEN 1 END AS PHONE,
       CASE APP WHEN 'mobile' THEN 1 END AS MOBILE,
       DEST_URI
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```